# Convert dynamic html to pdf with HiQPdf

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, pdf, knockout.js

I've been trying to get my HTML to accurately translate into a PDF for some time now but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code for the page:

```vb
Imports HiQPdf
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.UI

Partial Class MODULES_CostCalculator_CostCalculator
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim convertToPdf As Boolean = False

    Protected Sub printClick()
        convertToPdf = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        If (convertToPdf) Then
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("overriding render")
            Dim tw As TextWriter = New StringWriter()
            Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(tw)



            'render the html markup into the TextWriter
            MyBase.Render(htw)

            'get the current page html code
            Dim htmlCode As String = tw.ToString()

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(htmlCode)

            'convert the html to PDF

            'create html to pdf converter
            Dim htmlToPdfConv As HtmlToPdf = New HtmlToPdf()
            'htmlToPdfConv.MediaType = "print"

            'base url used to resolve images, css and script files
            Dim currentPageUrl As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

            'convert html to a pdf memory buffer
            Dim pdfBuffer As Byte() = htmlToPdfConv.ConvertHtmlToMemory(htmlCode, currentPageUrl)

            'inform the browser about the binary data format
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")

            'let the browser know how to open the pdf doc
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                               String.Format("attachment;     filename=ConvertThisHtmlWithState.pdf; size={0}",
                                                             pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()))

           'write the pdf buffer to http response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer)

            'call End() method of http response to stop ASP.NET page processing
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

        Else
            MyBase.Render(writer)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong? A lot of the HTML is linked to a Knockout ViewModel, so I'm not sure if that would be causing an issue.

To be clear, I can create PDF's of the page, but only with the HTML in the state it was when the page first loaded. If I change any of the data-bound HTML, it doesn't reflect when I try to make another PDF.

Comment: I do not have the library but from ASP.NET I would advise to try:
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()

Comment: If you don't mind trying something else how about :
Response.ClearHeaders(); This at beggining of the render method

Answer (score 0):

Priorplease try:

1. Adding clear:

   Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
2. After MyBase.Reder method

   htw.Flush()
3. At the before Response.End

   Response.Flush()
4. If nothing above works:

   Call support :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're changing the state of the page after it has rendered (using JavaScript), and you're expecting this: -

```
    MyBase.Render(htw)

    'get the current page html code
```

to give you the *current* state of the page. It won't - it will give you the state of the page as it was rendered. If you're using Knockout or anything other scripting to manipulate the DOM after the page has loaded, the server-side model of the page knows nothing of these changes.

Comment: any thoughts on how I could get the server side model to know about the changes?

Comment: You should ensure that your HTML is created from a data model that defines the state of the page as it's loaded, and can be updated by client-side code via webservice or httphandler calls.